# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir los datos de esta lista enlazada de tal manera que se visualice del primer elemento al último?

Tags: c++

Lo que pasa es que al mandarla imprimir de esta manera me muestra desde el último al primero y no quiero eso, quiero que sea al revés, sólo que no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo, puesto que apenas estoy aprendiendo sobre este tema. Este es el código, el lenguaje que utilizo es C++:

```
    //Lista con sus respectivos nodos
    struct rutas{
         string nombre, origen, destino;
         rutas *direccion;
    };

    rutas *original, *auxiliar, *atras;

    void verrutas(){
         if(original==NULL){
         cout << "No ha registrado rutas" <<endl;
         return;
         }
         auxiliar=original;
         cout <<"Rutas registrados " <<endl;
         while(auxiliar!=NULL){
              cout <<" Nombre de la ruta: " << auxiliar->nombre 
                    << " Origen: " << auxiliar->origen << " Destino: "<< 
                    auxiliar->destino<<endl;
              auxiliar=auxiliar->direccion;
              }
          }
```

Comment: Seguramente se te imprime *al revés* porque la guardas *al revés*. Pero como no muestras el código en que insertas datos, no puedo adivinarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice @PaperBirdMaster, lo mas seguro es que *empilas* (añades nodos por la cabeza) en vez de *encolar* (añades nodos por la cola) y la solución sería cambiar el código que añades nodos para *guardar* la cabeza. Pero bueno, esta solución que te paso te sirve para mostrar los elementos partiendo desde el último. Es una rutina recursiva, que es una forma diferente de hacerlo

```
struct rutas
{
   CString nombre, origen, destino;
   rutas *direccion;
};

rutas *original, *auxiliar, *atras;

void verrutas (rutas *_auxiliar)
{
   if (_auxiliar != NULL)
   {
      verrutas(_auxiliar->direccion);
      wcout << " Nombre de la ruta: " << (LPCTSTR) _auxiliar->nombre
         << " Origen: " << (LPCTSTR)_auxiliar->origen << " Destino: " <<
         (LPCTSTR)_auxiliar->destino << endl;
   }
}


void verrutas()
{
   if (original == NULL)
   {
      cout << "No ha registrado rutas" << endl;
      return;
   }
   cout << "Rutas registrados " << endl;
   verrutas (original);
}

int main()
{
    original = new rutas;
    original->nombre = _T("Ruta del norte");
    original->origen = _T("Paris");
    original->destino = _T("Bruselas");
    original->direccion = NULL;

    auxiliar = new rutas;
    auxiliar->nombre = _T("Tren de medianoche");
    auxiliar->origen = _T("Algueciras");
    auxiliar->destino = _T("Fuenlabrada");
    auxiliar->direccion = original;
    original = auxiliar;

    auxiliar = new rutas;
    auxiliar->nombre = _T("Ruta turística");
    auxiliar->origen = _T("Filadelfia");
    auxiliar->destino = _T("Alburquerque");
    auxiliar->direccion = original;
    original = auxiliar;

    verrutas();
}
```

Utilizo **CString** en vez de **string** por que me resulta más cómodo, pero tiene que funcionar con **string** igualmente. Como verás sobrecargo la rutina **verrutas** para que evitar que **void verrutas (rutas *_auxiliar)** muestre cada vez el mensaje *No ha registrado rutas*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]